# Why doesn't MonoDevelop code completion work for objects?

Tags: autocomplete, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, unityscript

I am using MonoDevelop 2.4.2, and code completion works fine for everything inside my class scope. But it doesn't work for properties/functions of instances and static classes.

For example, when typing:

`this.myFunct` - pops up
`MyStaticCla` - pops up
`MyStaticClass.myFun` - nothing happens
`myobject.myPrope` - nothing happens

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which unity do you mean? Ubuntu Unity or Unity3D?

Comment: Unity is not named Unity3D.  The tag and description of the tag are broken; unity-(3d) would be more appropriate, if parentheses are possible.  Anyway, MonoDevelop's autocomplete is completely unreliable.

Comment: the tag works pretty good for me..

Comment: ah ok now i understand what you mean.. however, can you suggest any other editor for unity3d with autocomplete?

Answer (score 4):

It seems there's an issue with the autocomplete files in mac os x. here's a link on the solution.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/121469/monodevelop-not-showing-autocomplete-intellisense.html

Comment: Can you next time please post the answer here?

Comment: You should post the relevant part here and add the link for reference. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

Unity has no autocomplete for private variables, static variables, and no description of some function methods.

Instead of finding the variable on autocomplete, you have to rewrite it and be sure to have the right spelling.